# filter with an or condition in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of data with a list of names and their supervisor. I am trying to filter this data so that only the given name is included and the names of people that person supervises so basically their name is in the employee column or the supervisor column. I have looked into the advanced filter options but haven't seen how that could work for my issue. I created a code using if statements but it is not filtering correctly. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
    For Each resource In wkbNewBook.Sheets("Availability").Range("A37:A116")
    rw = resource.Row
        If Not resource.Value = wkbNewBook.Sheets("Project List").Range("A6").Value Then
            resource.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Not wkbNewBook.Sheets("Availability").Cells(rw, "E").Value = wkbNewBook.Sheets("Project List").Range("A6").Value Then
            resource.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            resource.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
        If resource.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            resource.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next resource
```

The desired name is in cell A6 on a different sheet. The employee names are in column A and the supervisor names in column E.

Comment: have you tried using Pivot Tables with slicers?

Comment: @peege I have not tried pivot tables yet I am wanting to use vba code though because this needs to be done to multiple files generated by this master file and the desired name changes each time.